# JUnit: No runnable methods

Tags: java, junit

I am newbie in `JUnit`. I am fixing `JUnit` in `SonarQube` report and also increasing `Junit` code coverage. I came across of a `class` where there is no `@Test` `annotation`. The Exception thrown is as below:

```
No runnable methods java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
```

Test class below:

```
public class TestLimitPrice {

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() {

    JndiDataManager.init();
}

private LimitPriceBean      limitPrice;
private LimitPriceValidator validator;

@Before
public void setUp() {

    limitPrice = new LimitPriceBean();
    validator = new LimitPriceValidator(limitPrice);
}}
```

My  Question's are :

- In `Sonar Report` is it necessary for every `JUnit` to have atleast one `@Test` to pass ?
- Will empty `@Test` is good approach for increasing code coverage ?
- If in case any test case is not executing, then `assertEquals(true,true)` is good practice or should be avoided ?

**Update**

- Sonar Version 4.4.1
- JUnit Version 4.12
- Java 1.6-45

Comment: Which version o Sonar, JUnit, Java, etc? Without that it is a bit more difficult to go by... Seems like a bug though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My Question's are :
>
> - In Sonar Report is it necessary for every JUnit to have at least one
>     @Test to pass ?

I don't understand the question.

> - Will empty @Test is good approach for increasing code
>     coverage ?

No, for two reasons.

First, if the `@Test` method is truly empty, then there's no possibility to increase coverage. So let's assume that you have a `@Test` method that *does* execute some of your program code but that contains no assertions.

In this scenario, you've increased your test coverage by executing program code in a `@Test` but totally subverted the purpose of tests by not making any statements (assertions) about the expected outcome / outputs of that code. Let's say I've got

```
public int addTwoAndTwo() {
  return 2+2;
}
```

And a corresponding test

```
@Test public void testAddTwoAndTwo() {
   MyClass mc = new MyClass();   
   my.addTwoAndTwo();  // this method now "covered"
}
```

Now that `addTwoAndTwo` is "covered" I'm supposed to be able to maintain it with confidence that as long as the unit tests continue to pass, I haven't broken anything.

So let's do that. My new version is this:

```
public int addTwoAndTwo() {
  return 42;
}
```

After that change, my unit tests still succeed, so everything must be okay, right? Uhm... no. And that's why you need assertions:

```
@Test public void testAddTwoAndTwo() {
   MyClass mc = new MyClass();   
   assertThat(mc.addTwoAndTwo()).isEqualTo(4);  // this method now truly covered
}
```

> - If in case any test case is not executing, then
>     assertEquals(true,true) is good practice or should be avoided ?

The answer to this question should by now be obvious, but to be explicit, DO NOT DO THIS.

Comment: First question is "Does every `Junit` need to have at least single `test case` while building `sonar` report ?" I guess, it should have.